# Parse Android Notification not received

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, notifications, push-notification

I followed thus tutorial for parse notification on android
https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/android/native/existing

But I still can't receive the notifications in my App, this is my Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.walid.app_247_parse">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="com.walid.app_247_parse.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.walid.app_247_parse.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".Splash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".UserPhoneNumber" />
    <activity android:name=".MainPage" />
    <activity android:name=".ChatView" />
    <activity android:name=".Connect_Main" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyAZmjxQ_QZRG-0m-oMNcl0zC0H_eOEB8Jw" />

    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />


            <category android:name="com.walid.app_247_parse" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Also in my Launcher Activity I added these lines

```
 Parse.initialize(this, getResources().getString(R.string.ParseAppID), getResources().getString(R.string.ParseClientID));

    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

    ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("247APP", new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(com.parse.ParseException e) {
            Log.e("PARSE", "Successfully subscribed to Parse!");
        }


    });
```

And I can see the log of Successfully subscribed , and still whenever I send notification from parse.com nothing shown in my device.
Please note that I am testing the App on Asus Zenfone 2 running android 5.

Comment: post `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver` code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Call Parse.initialize from the onCreate method of your Application class (instead of your Launcher Activity)**

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

MyApplication.java

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Enable Local Datastore.
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

        // Add your initialization code here
        Parse.initialize(this, getResources().getString(R.string.ParseAppID), getResources().getString(R.string.ParseClientID));

        // Subscribe to a channel
        ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("twofourseven", new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.d("PARSE", "Successfully subscribed to Parse channel");
                } else {
                    Log.d("PARSE", "Failed to subscribe to Parse channel");
                }
            }
        });

        ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
        ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
        // Optionally enable public read access.
        // defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
        ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
    }
}
```

edit:

package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE" (missing .permission)

```
<permission android:protectionLevel="signature" android:name="com.walid.app_247_parse.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.walid.app_247_parse.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Comment: I followed your code , there is was a problem in the channel name "247APP" as  its starts with number, I changed it to twofourseven, and now it shows "Successfully subscribed to Parse channel" but it still can't recieve notifications , please note that I have in my app codes for user registration with parse, and loggin ,
Thanks

Comment: is it missing the .permission in <permission> and <uses-permission> tag?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Log.e("PARSE", "Successfully subscribed to Parse!");
```

to

```
if (e==null){
  Log.e("Parse", "Success");
} else {
  Log.e("PARSE", e.toString());
}
```

see what the error is or if it is actually successful for that portion.

Comment: Don't forget to set as question answered/complete when you are satisfied with your solution!